# Как считать и присвоить координаты элементу в Grid?

Tags: wpf, wpf-grid

Нужно сделать перетаскивание картинки в Grid, но в интернете я нашёл только считывание координат через Canvas, как это же осуществить в Grid?

Comment: Элемент в Grid может находиться только в какой-то конкретной ячейке, вы уверены, что вам нужен именно Grid?

Comment: Сильной важности в этом нет, я просто спросил для интереса) А вообще это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну перетаскивание из одной ячейки grid в другую можно сделать, но промежуточный canvas все равно потребуется, думаю. Так что особого смысла нет